# another meaning of 'cut trees'

Tags: meaning

> N.Y.P.D. needs to ***cut a few trees***.

The speaker is a police officer and she did a lot of overtime to pay her depts.
But NYPD didn't want her to do that and take a lot of money.
So NYPD had a division officer say to her that she should stop doing overtime.
And she said 'NYPD needs to cut a few trees' to a division officer.

My question is, what does 'cut a few tress' mean?
I googled it, but it only says it means felling.

Maybe it means 'a curtailment in the budget'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the original speaker meant "NYPD needs to cut some deadwood from the ranks." It is a common business expression. To cut deadwood is to let go those employees who do not contribute enough.